# generar nueva pagina php

Tags: php, html

soy nuevo en php y me gustaría saber como puedo generar una pagina html o php nueva incluyendo las clases de html

las comillas en la clase hola si las pongo dobles me tira error lo detecta como una cadena.

**ejemplo

```
 <?php 

  $contenido = "<html> <body class'hola'><h1> $t</h1> <p> $c </p></body></html>";

               file_put_contents('new.php', $contenido); 

                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a las comillas dobles, te recomiendo iniciar y terminar con comillas simples.

```
 $contenido = '<html> <body class"hola"><h1> $t</h1> <p>' . $c . '</p></body></html>';
```

También puedes poner una barra invertida antes de las comillas `\`, te recomiendo usar siempre simples por costumbre, ya que html usa dobles, por lo general con poner comillas simples delante y al final basta.

Puedes crear una página con la función `fwrite`  [Ver documentación.](https://php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php)

Tal que así.

```
$fp = fopen('NuevaPagina.php', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $contenido);
```